# mod_rewrite: RewriteRule redirect certain urls to specific php file

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i am trying  to figure ou ta  rewrite rule to direct certain urls to to specific php file:

the file is watch.php

the urls are like this `http://mysite/watch/193916/1/watch-skysports.html`

i want to redirect this

```
http://mysite/watch.php?file=watch/193916/1/watch-skysports.html
```

my try in the htaccess file

```
Options FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule watch/(*)/(*)/(*).html match.php?file=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

but it doesnt work
nb:mod_rewrite is enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have the right regex. The `*` isn't a wildcard, it's to indicate some number of characters. Try this instead:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(watch/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/.*\.html)$ /match.php?file=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: i am having problem as all my css,js,images links are relative and when i am on page http://mysite/watch/193916/1/watch-skysports.html the relative links will be `watch/193916/1/` how to fix this without having to edit all links to absolute urls

Comment: @user3080937 Try adding this to the header of your pages: `<base href="/" />`